# Jquery won't work on the second click of an option in combo box

Tags: jquery, html, combobox

I have a jquery code, at first all we can see is a combo box or a `<select>` tag. When I click for example the first option in the combo box, a button appears. When I click the button, the button disappears after. The problem is, when I click again the first option in the combo box, the button won't show anymore.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mySelect').change(function(){
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        $('#'+thisValue).fadeIn(1000);
    });


    $('.myButton').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

     $('.myButton').hide();

});
```

HTML:

```
<select class="mySelect">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="myButton1">One</option>
    <option value="myButton2">Two</option>
    <option value="myButton3">Three</option>
    <option value="myButton4">Four</option>
    <option value="myButton5">Five</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Click 1" id="myButton1" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 2" id="myButton2" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 3" id="myButton3" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 4" id="myButton4" class="myButton"/>
<input type="button" value="Click 5" id="myButton5" class="myButton"/>
```

Comment: gallery guy has a good answer. If you don't want it to work that way, my answer may work. But I think he has the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/ZJP4u/5/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mySelect').change(function(){
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        $('#'+thisValue).fadeIn(1000);
        $(".mySelect").val($(".myButton option:first").val());
    });


    $('.myButton').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

     $('.myButton').hide();

});
```

Comment: Try to click the option "One", then click the button. Click again the option "One" and it won't display the button anymore. It has no `CSS` sir.

Comment: But what I want is that it must not need to de-select anymore. Sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 0):

If you click "ONE" again, it will not show because the `SELECT` is not changed. Try clicking on TWO and then click again on ONE. The button1 will show.

In your jQuery, you are trying to fadeIn a button only when the option value changes in the select box.

This is what happens:

When you choose ONE in options, the button1 will fade in.
When you click the button1, it will disappear.
Now you are chosing ONE, which is already the selected option, so you click on ONE, it will not trigger CHANGE.

Answer (score 0):

Change your jquery to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //I added this section
    $('.mySelect').blur(function(){
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        $('#'+thisValue).fadeIn(1000);
    });
    //End

      $('.mySelect').change(function(){
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        $('#'+thisValue).fadeIn(1000);
    });    

    $('.myButton').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

     $('.myButton').hide();

});
```

The `blur()` handler will only fire if you click off of the select, but the onchange will never fire unless you change the selection and then change it back.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJP4u/4/)